# Gunicorn 502 gateway linked to sock file's permission denied error

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm setting up a django, gunicorn and nginx and when I visit the homepage I get a 502 gateway error.
The logs shows it's related to the permissions of the sock file

```
2017/07/01 09:59:18 [crit] 12237#12237: *23 connect() to unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp/revamp.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 105.49.30.134, server: $
```

And the permissions are

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 sammy www-data       0 Jul  1 05:29 revamp.sock
```

gunicorn service is setup like so

```
[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/revamp
ExecStart=/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the permissions look okay and systemctl status gunicorn is active.

**UPDATE**
The permissions for the folder are as follows

```
total 2128
drwxr-xr-x 3 sammy root        4096 Jun 28 05:21 account
-rw-r--r-- 1 sammy root          48 Jun 27 09:34 brain
-rw-r--r-- 1 sammy root     1037922 Jun 28 11:34 data.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy root     1087488 Jun 27 09:35 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x 4 sammy root        4096 Jun 28 05:21 gallery
-rw-r--r-- 1 sammy root        1326 Jun 27 09:34 hip-hop.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy root           0 Jun 27 09:34 lUhbv4PA5t.jpg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy root         249 Jun 27 09:34 manage.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy root         473 Jun 27 09:34 names.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 sammy root         211 Jun 27 09:34 nsfw
-rw-r--r-- 1 sammy root         417 Jun 27 09:34 obsene.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sammy root        1803 Jun 27 09:34 phrases.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 sammy root        4096 Jul  1 07:59 revamp
drwxrwxr-x 6 sammy sammy       4096 Jul  1 05:14 revampenv
srwxrwxrwx 1 sammy www-data       0 Jul  1 05:29 revamp.sock
-rw-r--r-- 1 sammy root          97 Jun 27 09:33 to do
```

Comment: How about the directories? `/home/sammy` , `/home/sammy/revamp` . Are they all accessible by the nginx ?

Comment: Maybe that's the root cause, there's also a 403 forbidden for even static files, was planning to fix this first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the file itself, but directories that lead to the file should be also accessible by the nginx process.

Check `/home/sammy`, `/home/sammy/revamp` directories' permissions.

Comment: permissions are for root updated the question, how can you change from root to user?

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri, I suggest you to move the socket path to somewhere both gunicorn and nginx can access.

Comment: the problem I believe isn't the sock file I initially copied the folder into root and it had root permissions which I believed I'd undone.

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri, What's the output of `ls -ld /home/sammy` and `ls -ld /home/sammy/revamp` ?  Belong to `root` does not mean it's accessible by nginx process because nginx is run as `www-data` user (I assumed you are using Ubuntu)

Comment: sammy@samuel-pc:~$ ls -ld /home/sammy
drwxr-xr-x 7 sammy sammy 4096 Jul  1 05:29 /home/sammy
sammy@samuel-pc:~$ ls -ld /home/sammy/revamp
drwx------ 7 sammy root 4096 Jul  1 05:29 /home/sammy/revamp

Comment: revamp might belong to root as you can see from the output

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri, so, `/home/sammy/revamp` is not access by `nginx` process (nginx process uses `www-data`, not `root`/ also permission does not allow group access the directory). Try this: `chgrp www-data /home/sammy/revamp` and `chmod g+rx /home/sammy/revamp`  to give `www-data` group access to the directory.

Comment: I've got a 403 forbidden an image file how can I set group access to www-data

Comment: @SamuelMuiruri, Please post a separate question with details (error message, nginx error log, image file serving configuration, ...) instead of comment.